# Unable to get the date in UTC format

Tags: java, calendar

I have written two functions - `today()` and `todayUTC()` - as:

```
public static Date today() {
  Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
  return cal.getTime();
}

public static Date todayUTC() {
  Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
  return cal.getTime();
}
```

But when I print the results of these functions using:

```
public void todayTest() {
  Date date1 = OOTBFunctions.today();
  System.out.println("today: "+date1);

  Date dateUTC1 = OOTBFunctions.todayUTC();
  System.out.println("todayUTC: "+dateUTC1);
}
```

I saw that both statements print the same value i.e.

```
today: Thu Aug 30 14:48:56 PDT 2012
todayUTC: Thu Aug 30 14:48:56 PDT 2012
```

Can anybody suggest what am I missing in UTC function that I am getting local timezone date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java uses the default Locale while printing and that is why you see that behavior. Use code like below to format and print it in the locale/format you want. Remember

- When you create a Date object, it is always in UTC.
- Display the date in the Locale of the user.
- Store the date in UTC.

Code

```
final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("the format you want");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
final String utcTime = sdf.format(new Date());
```

You doesn't need both today() and todayUTC() methods. keep and like below

```
public static Date nowInUTC() 
{
  return new Date();
}
```

You doesn't need to test anything.

Comment: actually i want the return type of the todayUTC() function to be a Date if i return sdf.format(new Date()), i get compiler error for return type mismatch

Comment: As I mentioned, the Date object is actually in UTC. You are confused because your sys out statement needs correction

Comment: i am confused whether i need to change the code for todayUTC() function or the code in todayTest function.

Comment: i am clear now.. updated my print statements. it works.. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Both of your methods will return the same value - a `Date` object doesn't have any notion of a  time zone (unlike a `Calendar`). A `Date` *just* represents an instant in time, stored internally as the number of milliseconds since midnight January 1st 1970, UTC. Effectively, you've got two methods which are equivalent to:

```
return new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

`Date.toString()` always uses the system default time zone.

If you want to maintain a date/time with a time zone, consider just using `Calendar`. If you want to format a particular instant in time in a time zone, just use `SimpleDateFormat` having set the time zone.

Ideally, change to use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) instead of `Date` or `Calendar` though - it's a much cleaner API.

Comment: #Jon Skeet How do you find the time to answer so many questions within 1 days. (Plus your all answers are the best) . Are you socialised ? Do you enjoy your life properly (Going pubs, playing games, hang out with friends ,enjoying time with GF/wife ,go out with kids to park (if you have any) ?

Comment: That's even better. You're a star. I wish I could spend time in learning like you. :)